# Optional XML Tag in Simple Transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, abap

I am newbie working with Simple Transformation, I need to get a XML from from internal tables. Some tables have no information (records), so I am trying to make a condition in the Simple transformation, what I need to do is TO HIDE the tag `User` and its internal tag and attributes IF THERE ARE NO RECORDS IN TABLES and SHOW IT WHEN THERE ARE RECORDS, but I can't do it...

I’m hoping someone will just see what I’m doing wrong and point out how dumb I am… This is the code what I have tried with:

```
<tt:cond check="not-initial(ref('.DEPARTAMENT.DOCUMENTINFO.USER.'))">

<User tt:value-ref=".DEPARTAMENT.DOCUMENTINFO.USER."/>
            
<User>
  <tt:attribute name="UserName" value-ref=".DEPARTAMENT.DOCUMENTINFO.USER.USERNAME"/>
  <tt:attribute name="RFCUser" value-ref=".DEPARTAMENT.DOCUMENTINFO.USER.RFCUSER"/>
  <tt:attribute name="Residence" value-ref=".DEPARTAMENT.DOCUMENTINFO.USER.RESIDENCE"/>
  <Address>
    <tt:attribute name="Street" value-ref=".DEPARTAMENT.DOCUMENTINFO.USER.ADDRESS.STREET"/>
    <tt:attribute name="Num" value-ref=".DEPARTAMENT.DOCUMENTINFO.USER.ADDRESS.NUM"/>
    [....]
   </Address>
 </User>
    
</tt:cond>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the ABAP code. Thank you. NB: the minimal example needs an internal table with only one component, others are superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't give the definition of your ABAP variable, and what exactly is wrong, so difficult to answer if your condition is correct. So let me propose an answer with full minimal reproducible example (as recommended by Stack Overflow, see Help menu).

If you have this ABAP code:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_user,
         username TYPE string,
       END OF ty_user,
       ty_users TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_user WITH EMPTY KEY.
DATA(users) = VALUE ty_users( ( username = `TOTO` ) ).
CALL TRANSFORMATION ztest SOURCE users = users RESULT XML DATA(xml).
```

and this `ztest` Simple Transformation:

```
<?sap.transform simple?>
<tt:transform xmlns:tt="http://www.sap.com/transformation-templates">
  <tt:root name="USERS"/>
  <tt:template>
    <theroot>
      <tt:cond check="not-initial(USERS)">
        <Users>
          <tt:loop ref=".USERS">
            <User>
              <tt:attribute name="UserName" value-ref="USERNAME"/>
            </User>
          </tt:loop>
        </Users>
      </tt:cond>
    </theroot>
  </tt:template>
</tt:transform>
```

that ​would produce this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
​<theroot>
​  <Users>
​    <User UserName="TOTO"/>
​  </Users>
​</theroot>
```

If the internal table is empty, that would produce this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
​<theroot/>
```

Concerning what is wrong

Comment: Really helpful !!! I apreciate it so much. thank you !!! :))